# Is there a way of installing Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Win10 (v1709) without using the Store?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1709

The Microsoft Store app is disabled by Group Policy by my university. I have administrator rights on my computer and I was wondering if there was a way of installing Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) directly? Or maybe via Chocolatey or some other command line method? I would like to download and install the Ubuntu  on windows without using the Microsoft store.

Note that since version 1709 (Fall Creator's Upgrade), only enabling Developer Mode is no longer sufficient.

Comment: You can just follow the documentation:

Setup WSL 2:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Download and install:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Answer (score 97, accepted):

#### Info: I tried this on a VM with Win10 Pro (v1709 & 1803) with stock Group Policy (i.e. as-is with a fresh installation).

<sub>That is: turning the Store off in `gpedit.msc` did not make a difference...</sub>

---

According to [Microsoft's "Windows Server Installation Guide"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-on-server):

> Note that this answer shows the steps for Debian only. However, everything is the same for Ubuntu, SLES, openSUSE, and Kali - the only difference will be in the name of the EXE (and the URL you use).

1. **Activate `Windows Subsystem for Linux`.**

   - Via the `Windows Features` GUI: e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> --> `OptionalFeatures.exe`
   - With PowerShell (as administrator): `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`.
2. **Download the Linux-package.**

   - Choose your distro. Simply use one of these URLs:

     - Debian: `https://aka.ms/wsl-debian-gnulinux`
     - Ubuntu 18.04: `https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804`
     - Ubuntu 16.04: `https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1604`
     - openSUSE: `https://aka.ms/wsl-opensuse-42`
     - SLES: `https://aka.ms/wsl-sles-12`
     - Kali: `https://aka.ms/wsl-kali-linux`
   - Via PowerShell, run `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-debian-gnulinux -OutFile ~/Debian.zip -UseBasicParsing`.

     - If you do not need the progress-bar, add `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';` in the front of the command.
     - Note that `~/Debian.zip` can be changed to whatever path and name you want.
   - You can also download it "per manus" - feed the URL into your browser (or download manager) and you can get it this way, too.
3. **Unzip the downloaded archive and place it into its destination path.**

   - Note that you can use any path - be it `~\IHateUbuntu\SLES_WSL`, be it `C:\Ubuntu`, etc.p.p.. It must, however, be on your system's drive (usually `C:\`) <sup>Thanks, [@Matt Wenham](https://superuser.com/questions/1271682/is-there-a-way-of-installing-windows-subsystem-for-linux-on-win10-v1709-withou#comment2155243_1272559)!</sup>
   - Via PowerShell: `Expand-Archive <ARCHIVE> <ITS_NEW_PATH>`
   - Via the File Explorer's GUI
   - Or via any zipping tool, such as 7-Zip.
4. **Run `Debian.exe`, which is inside the unzipped folder.**

   - For the other distros, you just have to look for the correct EXE.
   - This will now "install" your distro.
5. **Set your username and password.**

   - If error `0x80070005` shows up, you need to run the EXE as administrator. <sup>Thanks, [@March Ho](https://superuser.com/questions/1271682/is-there-a-way-of-installing-windows-subsystem-for-linux-on-win10-v1709-withou#comment2071051_1272559)!</sup>
6. It is *recommended* to **update all software at the first start.**

   - In Debian & Ubuntu, this is done by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.
7. *(Optional)* **Put your EXE into the Start Menu.**

   - Simply put a hard link of `Debian.exe` into `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.
8. *(Optional)* **Repeat for as many distributions as you like to have.**

---

You are good to go now. Run `Debian.exe` whenever you want WSL to run.

Comment: If you're getting the error `0x80070005`, you need to run the exe file as administrator.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it is possible to install these for _all users_ at once?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Since it is installed into whatever Path you like (e.g. `C:`), providing access (and links) for all users should not be a problem. However, I do not know how to create links for multiple users. Something along `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "<USER_DIR>" -Name "<DISTRO>" -Value "<DISTRO_EXE_PATH>"` should work.

Comment: Top instructions. Thanks. FYI: If you are like me, and unzipped the distro in a silly location the first time... You will find `wslconfig /list` and `wslconfig /unregister` are your friends...

Comment: I believe that the distribution should be extracted onto your system drive, as mentioned here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#troubleshooting

Comment: Note: the `0x80070005` errors pops for a lot of reasons. If you want to look for workarounds, look here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3020

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this while trying to install Debian, note that the Store version of Debian has been updated to Debian 10, but the aka.ms link is still Debian 9. Opened an issue for it here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/563

Comment: The downloaded image will install the WSL 1 version (that is what happened to me). But if you want wsl2 you can run `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2` for example

Comment: Find the list with all distros here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Answer (score 18):

This is a short procedure, applies for Windows 10 Fall Creators update and above.

1. Enable "Windows Subsystem For Linux" feature from `OptionalFeatures.exe` and restart PC. From [Windows Server Installation Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-on-server).
2. Download  any one of the following file (with any browser or any download manager):

   - Ubuntu:: https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1604 redirects to https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/Ubuntu.1604.2017.711.0_v1.appx ([old link](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/Ubuntu.1604.2017.711.0_v1.appx)).
   - OpenSUSE:: https://aka.ms/wsl-opensuse-42 redirects to https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/openSUSE-42_v1.appx ([old link](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/openSUSE-42_v1.appx)).
   - SLES:: https://aka.ms/wsl-sles-12 redirects to https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/SLES-12_v1.appx ([old link](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/SLES-12_v1.appx)).
3. Open Appx packages with [7ZIP](https://www.7-zip.org/). Extract only the **executable file (e.g. Ubuntu.exe) and install.tar.gz** in any drive or any folder. Double click on that executable file and it will be installed.

**Notes::** You can now [install any GNU/Linux distribution](https://superuser.com/a/1313540/726810) using compressed RootFS tarballs (only .tar.gz) provided in distribution sites or from docker images.

Answer (score 6):

You can (1) download the installers from the Windows Store or (2) download a distribution file and install it using tools such as [lxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) or [WSL Distrolauncher](https://github.com/yuk7/WSL-DistroLauncher).

- You can install Ubuntu 18 or many other distributions using the second option.

---

**Downloading the installer from the Windows Store**

You can download the [installers from the Windows Store using Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual). For instance, you can download the Ubuntu 16 version using the following command

```
PS> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1604 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing
```

In the above command, the output file is `Ubuntu.appx`. It must be named in that way. You can run that application to install the Ubuntu.

```
PS> Ubuntu.appx
```

---

**Using LxRunOffline**

First, you must download some distribution file. There are many distribution files available in [the lxRunOffline wiki](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline/wiki).

For instance, to install the same Ubuntu 16 from the Microsoft Windows Store, you can download the file at

```
https://lxrunoffline.apphb.com/download/UbuntuFromMS/16
```

Then, you can install the linux distribution using lxRunOffline

```
# lxrunoffline install -n <name> -d <folder> -f <distribution file>

C:\wsl> lxrunoffline install -n copy -d c:\wsl\copy -f 16.04.2-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
```

To run the distribution, you may use the same lxRunOffline

```
C:\wsl> lxrunoffline run -n copy -w
```

---

**Using a DistroLauncher**

You can use some DistroLauncher. There are many versions based on the [Microsoft example](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher) to create custom linux distributions for WSL. For instance, you can use the [Yuk7 version](https://github.com/yuk7/WSL-DistroLauncher).

You must download a distribution file and the `launcher.exe`. To use the same distribution file mentioned above, you must rename the distribution file to `rootfs.tar.gz` and the launcher to the distribution name you want. Later you must run the launcher as an Administrator (I got errors running it as a normal user)

```
PS> ren launcher.exe mydistro.exe
PS> ren .\16.04.2-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz rootfs.tar.gz
PS> .\mydistro
```

The first time you run the launcher, it installs and run the distribution. The next time, it runs the linux distribution.

---

After installing, you can manage the distributions using the `wslconfig` or the `lxrunoffline` commands.

**NOTE:** In addition to the distribution files mentioned above, you can create a new file based on other linux distributions. You may try the instructions included in the [WSLInstall project](https://github.com/Biswa96/WSLInstall/blob/master/Make_RootFS.md). You may need [additional steps](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline/wiki/Alpine-Linux) after the installation to start the new linux correctly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Enable WSL on PowerShell as Administrator:

   ```
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux"
   ```
2. Install the distribution of your choice using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). e.g. for 
   Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS:

   ```
   choco install wsl-ubuntu-1804
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea you can install a WSL distribution with Chocolatey

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
wsl --install -d <DISTRO-NAME>
```

This is the [recommended way](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).