# Can you install any other distros in Win10's "Windows Subsystem for Linux"?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

The "*Windows Server Installation [Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server)*" links [to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) "*Manually download Windows Subsystem for Linux distro packages*", which mentions several distributions that are officially provided: Debian, Kali, Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, Fedora, and SLES

Since we have Debian and Slackware based distros at hand:

- Is it possible to use any distributions/tree other than those, such as Arch?
- Are there any downsides to not using the official distributions?

I am particularly interested in a way that avoids using the Windows Store, as it can be [blocked](https://superuser.com/q/1271682/703240) by Group Policies.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76025/discussion-on-question-by-flolilolilo-can-you-install-any-other-distros-in-win10).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This is tested in Windows 10 v1709 and the procedure may change in future Windows 10 builds*

1. **Compile Installer:** 
    We have to compile an executable to call the [`WslRegisterDistribution()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826870(v=vs.85).aspx) function: 
    <sup>*(not expected for this documented function to change)*</sup>

   ```cpp
   #include <Windows.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   typedef HRESULT (WINAPI* RegisterDistro)(PCWSTR distroName, PCWSTR tarGzFilename);

   int main() {
     int wargc;
     wchar_t** wargv;
     wargv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &wargc);
     HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryExW(L"wslapi.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32);
     RegisterDistro func = (RegisterDistro)GetProcAddress(dll, "WslRegisterDistribution");
     HRESULT result = func(wargv[1], wargv[2]);
     (result == S_OK) ? printf("%ls installed\n", wargv[1]) : printf("Error: 0x%x\n", result);
   }
   ```

   Compile this with any C compiler (e.g. `gcc`), letting the executable name `Wslnstall.exe` (needed for step #3), and I have a compiled version of this in my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/Biswa96/WSLInstall/releases)
2. **Download `.tar.gz` RootFS:** 
    There are many ways to get the RootFS of a distro (e.g. from ISO file, from docker image, using `debootstrap` command etc.) and from my personal experience, there are some conditions that to be present in that `.tar.gz` file, such as the `.tar.gz` file should be compressed with **gzip only**, contain a valid `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` binary, and `/etc/passwd` file (as usual).

   - These are just guidelines *users may skip*, and here I omit these steps with a direct link to a [pre-built](http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/releases/x86_64/) `.tar.gz` for Alpine (only download the `.tar.gz`)
3. **Install:** 
    Place the compiled executable (step #1) and `.tar.gz` (step #2) within the *same folder* you want to install, running from within that folder:

   ```bsh
   # WslInstall.exe <distro_name> <file_name.tar.gz>
     WslInstall.exe Alpine alpine-minirootfs-xxx.tar.gz
   ```

The Alpine distribution should now be installed.

Comment: You could also P/Invoke that via PowerShell/C#. Would avoid the need for a separate executable, if that's desired or the environment makes it impractical.

Comment: @Bob I know that with C#. But using C one has many option like VS, cygwin, mingw etc. If you know that with Powershell the I've a question in SO, can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47250994/8928481 and reply your answer in this link.

Comment: I'll have a look at it tomorrow (if I remember) - no particular reason it shouldn't work, so it's odd that it didn't seem to work for you. But I don't have WSL on this particular machine so it'll have to wait a bit.