# Get a Linux Distro for WSL on Windows 1703

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1703

I am using Windows 10 on my company Laptop. I do have the privileges to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux on my System and I successfully did so.

However, the currently available Linux Distros for WSL all require the most recent Windows version, 1709, which I do not have and cannot get, due to company policy.

I am currently stuck to Windows 10 1703. As a result I get [the cryptic `0x80073CFD` error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/748119dc-0e81-422c-a7d0-aba2cb1fc884/cant-install-my-updated-appxpackage-on-windows-10-error-0x80073cfd-a-prerequisite-file-could-not?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) when I try to start Linux. This is Windows' way of telling the user that their version of Windows is too old for the requested Application.

As there are blog posts and such where people write about running Linux on Windows 10 1703, there must be appx-packages out there, that will run on Windows 1703. Can anyone provide me with a source for such (outdated) packages?

Or can the most recent versions be hacked to not require an up to date Windows? Maybe that's a better approach.

---

### For completeness sake

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1271682/114609), for the following reasons:

1. The referenced question is about installing WSL. As stated, I was already able to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). That is not my problem.
2. My stated problem is that available appx-packages require Windows 1709, which I cannot have. This problem is neither addressed nor answered in the referenced question.
3. I specifically state that I get an error message saying my version of Windows is too old. This problem is not addressed in the referenced question, which concerns the most recent version of Windows.
4. I specifically ask for a source for appx-packages that will run on Windows 10 1703. That information is not provided in the answers to the referenced question, b/c the user does not need them, b/c they are on Windows 10 1709.
5. I specifically ask if the most recent versions, i.e. the ones mentioned in the referenced question, can be hacked to not require version 1709 anymore. That information is not provided in the answers to the referenced question, b/c the user is on Windows 10 1709.

Comment: The legacy beta WSL instances is no longer supported and they cannot be upgraded.  If your unable to upgrade to 1709 you are out of luck.

Comment: WSL was never intended as a replacement for running a full linux in a VM; rather, it was a way of providing access to certain console-based Linux utilities and scripts on a Windows system.

Comment: Even if you install a newer version of the Ubuntu instance on the legacy version of WSL, none of the improvements within WSL on the newer builds of Windows will be accessible.  How you install the version of Ubuntu WSL that is available on 1703 has remained unchanged though.

Comment: The newer WSL cannot run on 1703.  That is impossible the only thing that is possible is to install the legacy WSL Ubuntu instance, which is the only WSL instance, that exists on 1703.

Comment: @Ramhound And where can I get this particular instance?

Comment: @user1129682 - You run `lxrun /install` in an elevated command prompt provided you already enabled the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` feature (which I assume you have since you said you had already installed it).  `lxrun` is the legacy tool and only works on 1703, if you were running 1709+, an entirely different command would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My stated problem is that available appx-packages require Windows
>   1709, which I cannot have. This problem is neither addressed nor
>   answered in the referenced question.

The current WSL instances that are distributed on the Windows Store only support 1709 and greater.

> I specifically ask for a source for appx-packages that will run on Windows 10 1703. That information is not provided in the answers to the referenced question, b/c the user does not need them, b/c they are on Windows 10 1709.

This is not possible.

> I specifically ask if the most recent versions, i.e. the ones mentioned in the referenced question, can be hacked to not require version 1709 anymore. That information is not provided in the answers to the referenced question, b/c the user is on Windows 10 1709.

This is not possible

> As there are blog posts and such where people write about running Linux on Windows 10 1703, there must be appx-packages out there, that will run on Windows 1703. Can anyone provide me with a source for such (outdated) packages?

All you have to do is run `lxrun /install` in an elevated command prompt.  The correct Ubuntu WSL instance will be automatically downloaded and installed.

> However, the currently available Linux Distros for WSL all require the
>   most recent Windows version, 1709, which I do not have and cannot get,
>   due to company policy.

The only WSL instance that is compatible with your system is Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.  You can perform a [forced](https://superuser.com/questions/1317619/can-i-upgrade-my-existing-ubuntu-installation-in-wsl-from-16-04-to-18-04) upgrade to 18.04 but I cannot suggest performing an upgrade using that method.  If you need an offline method to install Ubuntu 16.04 WSL on Windows 10 v1703 you can use [lxRunOffline v1.1.0](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline/releases).

> The following instructions are for users running Windows 10
>   Anniversary Update or Windows 10 Creators Update:
>
> 1. Enable **Developer Mode**
> 2. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName
>      Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
> 3. Reboot
> 4. Open a command prompt. Type **bash** and hit enter
>
> The first time you run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, you'll be prompted
>   to accept Canonical's license. Once accepted, WSL will download and
>   install the Ubuntu instance onto your machine, and a "Bash on Ubuntu
>   on Windows" shortcut will be added to your start menu.

Source: [Windows 10 Anniversary Update and Creators Update WSL Install & Uninstall Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-legacy)

Comment: `Bash.exe` and `lxrun /install` can both be used to intilize the Ubuntu instance by the way.

Comment: Worked! `lxrun /install` fetches the correct image for Windows 10 1703 from the Windows Store (!), even though Windows Store is disabled for me. Had to enable developer mode first, as described in [the source you provided](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-legacy)