# WSL is enabled on windows but not able to launch Ubuntu.exe even after several restarts

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Not able to launch Ubuntu,

```
The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. Please enable it and try again.
See https://aka.ms/wslinstall for details.
Press any key to continue...
```

**Output of WSL status:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux


FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)
Description      : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
RestartRequired  : Required
State            : Enabled
CustomProperties :
```

I have restarted many times and not able to launch Ubuntu1804.

**Edit-1:**

I have tried to launch `.exe` file using admin as well as the user privileges, through double-clicking the `.exe` file as well as from PowerShell itself.

Comment: Probably you are using old Windows 10 version. wSL feature is out of beta in several years ago. Clean install of latest Windows 10 OS may solve your issue.

Comment: @shaikmoeed - Why does it say `Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)`, that isn't right, what version of Windows 10 are you running?  You would have to be running 1703 which is 2 years old.

Comment: Try using lxrun instead.

Comment: @Ramhound Current version is `1607`. Maybe I need to update it to the latest version `1909`.

Comment: @shaikmoeed - Windows 10 version 1607 has not been supported for nearly 2 years.  You really should upgrade to the most recent version.  Your issues are due to the fact, you have a version with only the beta version, which means your WSL Ubuntu instance will be 4 years old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to launch .exe file using admin as well as the user privileges, through double-clicking the .exe file as well as from PowerShell itself.

You are using Windows 10 Version 1607, which means you have to use `lxrun.exe` and `bash.exe` to manage your WSL instance. `wsl.exe` and `wslconfig.exe` are not applicable to Windows 10 version 1607.

Here are the steps you must follow to use WSL on Windows 10 version 1607.

> The following instructions are for users running Windows 10
>   Anniversary Update or Windows 10 Creators Update:
>
> 1. Enable **Developer Mode**
> 2. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName
>      Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
> 3. Reboot
> 4. Open a command prompt. Type **bash** and hit enter
>
> The first time you run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, you'll be prompted
>   to accept Canonical's license. Once accepted, WSL will download and
>   install the Ubuntu instance onto your machine, and a "Bash on Ubuntu
>   on Windows" shortcut will be added to your start menu.

Sources:

- [Get a Linux Distro for WSL on Windows 1703](https://superuser.com/questions/1346511/get-a-linux-distro-for-wsl-on-windows-1703/1346906#1346906)
- [Windows 10 Anniversary Update and Creators Update WSL Install & Uninstall Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-legacy)

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. One small doubt, If I run any server(eg: Redis) from this bash, will it work the same as it is running on Linux machine or it works the same it works on a windows machine?

Comment: @shaikmoeed - I am not sure I understand the question.  Only WSL 2 runs the actual Linux kernel.

Comment: Okay, I need WSL 2 then. Thank you.

Comment: @shaikmoeed - WSL 2 required Windows 10 version 2004 which isn't out yet

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me:

1. Run windows + R
2. type SystemPropertiesAdvanced
3. click settings in performance group
4. In advanced tab, deselect the automatically manage paging file size for all drives
5. Select custom size and enter 800 for initial size, 1024 for maximum size.
6. Apply changes and restart.

Reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/849#issuecomment-322163360