# Installing "Ubuntu" (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Win10 without using the Store?

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Since I'm not allowed to comment on a flagged Solution (Sorry, kinda not sorry..?)
-> [Is there a way of installing Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on Win10 (v1709) without using the Store?](https://superuser.com/questions/1271682/is-there-a-way-of-installing-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux-on-win10-v170)

My Question: is there a way/Link/URL to Download the "blend" version of Ubuntu?  The Microsoft Store offers "Ubuntu 16.04", "Ubuntu 18.04" and just "Ubuntu".
I'd like to install the last one, since I'm gonna upgrade the distro to the latesest version anyways. It bothers me to open "Ubuntu 1804" when it's actually 1810, 2004, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way/Link/URL to Download the "blend" version of Ubuntu?

You would have to download the Appx for [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).  A Microsoft developer submitted links to the [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) Appx files on Github in the past.

In order to download the version of you want, there is a third-party website ([Adguard](https://store.rg-adguard.net/)), that scraps a Microsoft Store page for the download link.  If you were to use that website, and provide it a link to [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), it would provide a link to [CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc.appx](http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/c4a0955e-2d68-4c61-8c19-4c4ffbff7b55?P1=1581077210&P2=402&P3=2&P4=gS%2B9ytohOyQnCEnukWSUWIl2VfuRWT5arGiwm0FEMJF3bTJ0Gck%2BkXxZ007t7tCHBYNmWfkqjFZC7W1X8OAgSw%3D%3D)

Comment: In order to perform the offline install, you need to use a URL shorter, Invoke-WebRequest is incompatible with the link.  Since that required an account to some service, and that isn't really what you asked, if that's what you need I will let you figure it out.

Comment: I really just wanted the Appx package you provided with your last link. Downloading and installing don't need any extra steps. Download, double click or powershell Add-AppxPackage ./filename.Appx work perfectly fine!

Comment: Now, I'm wondering why MS offers short links for "Ubuntu 16.04" and "Ubuntu 18.04" like https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1604 but not for "Ubuntu". I assume, the links found by https://store.rg-adguard.net/ will change periodically.
edit:I just noticed the link you posted already expired

Comment: The link will change but the file will only change when there is an update