# Kali Linux not updating in WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2

Hello everyone I installed fresh Windows 11 and enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux and Virtual Machines and switched to WSL2, and installed Kali Linux from the Microsoft Store.

When I tried to update the repo, It was stuck a 0%

So I changed the http to https in sources.list As it was widely suggested fix.

However even doing so did not change anything what could be the Root cause of this behaviour?

[Check the screenshot please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZhWS.png)

```
UPDATED:

I tried Going to visiting following URLS in the browser

> http://http.kali.org/kali/
> https://http.kali.org/kali/

Both Opened Successfully!

Then Tried the following command
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
Which threw an error Message:

gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation

so I Installed it manually as I couldn't install from apt directly from terminal,
After installing the gnupg2 it threw the same error:

gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation 

Then I tried adding the following repos to sources.list

deb http://http.kali.org/ /kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/ /wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free 

But neither of them succeeded
```

[check the screenshot of gnupg ERROR Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq7Ow.png)

Comment: Same issue on Windows 11 Pro.  From what I have read, it is a Kali issue. I have Kali Virtual Machines in both VMware (as I type here) on Windows 10 and in Hyper-V on Windows 11. Both Kali VMs update just fine. It is not working in WSL2.

Comment: A few days back I installed the same way in my cousin's machine who was at my house.

Same thing happened with him as well. I just asked him to see if its working on his machine now,

It's working just fine so it's my router issue???
Or should I contact my ISP?

Comment: Ask your ISP and see if they can help.

Comment: Try the solutions listed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429729/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux-after-dist-upgrade)

Comment: @GamingWorld Just to confirm -- I know you said you installed from the Microsoft Store, right?  I know there's [a problem](https://superuser.com/q/1691763/1210833) when Kali is installed via `wsl --install -d kali-linux`, but it's different.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes! I installed it from the Store and I Installed it from Store for my Cousin as well his System was not updating either but at his home its working fine, I believe its happening on my IP?

Comment: @GamingWorld Could very well be.  Some of the discussion in the link Ramhound gave you can hopefully help determine that.

Comment: Moreover I recently changed my Router IP's last address from `IP.IP.0.1` to `IP.IP.1.1`
So I switched it back to `IP.IP.0.1` just to confirm it but it still did the same

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks I tried all the Possible ways suggested I opened both `http://http.kali.org/kali/` and `https://http.kali.org/kali/` Both displayed with no Issue

and Solution 2 `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6`
Threw Error: ` gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation` As You know I can't install any due to not being able to connect, Lastly I tried adding all mentioned repos in the list none of them accomplished!

Comment: @John I don't think this could be an Issue as My Laptop is working fine with Linux as its primary OS Running Well

Comment: @GamingWorld - [You can download the packages manually and install them.](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gnupg2). That should be enough

Comment: You can download it within Windows and drop it into your Kali instance to install it

Comment: @Ramhound I just did installed gnupg2 it installed fine however when I tried the command `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6`
It threw the exact same error again :|

Comment: You should [edit] your question with the error message and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Ramhound done!